# response from file hosting service

Tags: javascript, web

When a user enters captcha and then clicks download on a file hosting site (lets say 4shared.com), the download starts. Is clicking on download (after entering captcha) sends a request to server or is it just a javascript action?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `captcha` is validated just by javascript, one could easily bypass capture by sending request directly to server (using curl, for example). So it would defeat the purpose of `captcha` as a tool against automatic downloads by script.

So it must be validated on server.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely "download" button belongs to a form which redirect browser to some action that can, in case of correct captcha, set [Content-Disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) and other headers and read file bytes...

Answer (score 0):

It usually triggers an AJAX request which generates/activates and returns the download link. Sometimes it also submits a classic form where the server responds with a redirect to the file or the file contents.